# Why ngGridEventEndCellEdit is called from two different grids?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have ngGridEventEndCellEdit in two controllers

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function(data) {
        console.log('data: ' + data.targetScope.row.entity);
});
```

but it's called from second (B) ng-grid too. grids and controllers are in two different views (managed by routeProvider).

Why ngGridEventEndCellEdit from controller A is called on ng-grid B (where controller B is servicing ng-grid B and it has it's own version) ?
Why event from grid A calls two (both) ngGridEventEndCellEdit methods ?

Comment: I found examples to use data.targetScope.gridId, but whats that? it returns ng1420908599317

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.

1. I had ngController attached to main view in **< body ng-app....**    tag
2. I had two controllers in two files defined

   angular.module('myCtrl', []).controller(....

[] are bad, because it overwrites previous definition of a controller, I had to do

```
angular.module('myCtrl').controller(....
```